# 'else if' cant use variable from TryParse

Tags: c#

```
double x;
double y;
string strx = TextBoxX.Text;
string stry = TextBoxY.Text;

if (!double.tryParse(strx, out double a))
    {MessageBox.Show("Incorrect input");}

else if (!double.tryParse(stry, out double b))
    {MessageBox.Show("Incorrect input");}

x = a;
y = b; <---
```

The problem is that x and receive value of a, but y cant do the same for b.
I understand its because its within 'else' and might not get executed, but if I remove the else, then if both textboxes are empty or not numbers I'll get two error popups...

Any help resolving the issue?

Comment: why do you need `a` and `b` at all? why not use `out x`, `out y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should question how your logic is set.

Right now, if either or both textboxes are wrong, the user sees the ambiguous "Incorrect input".  I would find this frustrating.  Where's the incorrect input?  Is it the first text box?  The second?  Both?

As you develop better UIs, the answer will be to validate each text box and have each one that is wrong turn a color or provide some other feedback on the form itself.  Otherwise, imagine how ugly the logic will get when you're presenting a form to the user with 20 different fields.

However, if you're only going to use two fields, and you want to have some logic, try something like this (note that in doing this, I got rid of the `else`, as well, so b will always be set):

```
double x;
double y;
string strx = TextBoxX.Text;
string stry = TextBoxY.Text;
List<string>() invalids = new List<string>();

if (!double.tryParse(strx, out double a))
    {invalids.Add("boxX");}

if (!double.tryParse(stry, out double b))
    {invalids.Add("boxY")}

if invalids.Length != 0
    {MessageBox.Show("Incorrect inputs in " + String.Join(", ", invalids.ToArray());}

x = a;
y = b;
```

The user will enjoy a single box that tells them of all the errors more than multiple pop-up boxes, or having to hit OK each time and see that there are more errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!double.TryParse(strx, out double a) || !double.TryParse(stry, out double b))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect input");
    return;
}
```